# How to connect Django to AWS RDS

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I was following a Django tutorial but now I can't connect to the database.

My settings.py file looks like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'masteruser',
        'PASSWORD': 'passKode',
        'HOST': 'w3-django-project.czmrkj1y3qxu.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

But when I run the command

> python manage.py migrate

I get errors as shown below:

```
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 269, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "w3-django-project.czmrkj1y3qxu.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.31.11.179), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 136, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 574, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 81, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 57, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 330, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 306, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 288, in ensure_connection
    with self.wrap_database_errors:
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 269, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/amen/Documents/PRJKTZ/PYTHON/W3Django/myworld/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "w3-django-project.czmrkj1y3qxu.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.31.11.179), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

And the logs on the database show this:
[image: Database logs]

What does it mean and how can I fix it?
I am running Python 3.10 on Ubuntu22

Answer (score 1):

From the logs, it seems like the RDS instance is not accessible to the Django server.

As you haven't shared the RDS configuration, the most probable issues are:

1. The Publicly Accessible property of the DB instance is set to No: You can change the accessibility under the `Connectivity and Security` tab of the RDS instance console. Refer to [this](https://www.intelligentdiscovery.io/controls/rds/aws-rds-publicly-accessible) for detailed step-by-step instructions.
2. Incorrect VPC Security group settings: The security group on RDS is the default VPC Security group, with restrictive inbound rules. Create a new inbound rule and the type of connection `PostgreSQL` and depending on the level of public access you require, change the source IP CIDR. You can refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-security-groups.html) for the same.

After this, verify with this telnet command

```
telnet w3-django-project.czmrkj1y3qxu.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 5432
```

to check if you can connect to the RDS instance before attempting to migrate.